# How to detect similarity ratio of texts with php?

Tags: php, similarity

Let's say i have two sentences:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

"The quick brown bunny jumps over the lazy cat"

Is there an algorithm to detect similarity ratio of these two sentences ? For example:

```
function similarity_ratio($text1, $text2) {
code code code
return $similarity_ratio;
}
$text1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$text2 = "The quick brown cat jumps over the lazy chicken";
echo similarity_ratio($text1, $text2);
// output 88%
```

Comment: In the example should be output 100% ^^ I will think of one

Comment: Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: @DanielsPitkevičs yes my bad, fixed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function similarity_ratio($text1, $text2) {
     similar_text($text1, $text2, $similarity_ratio);
     return $similarity_ratio;
}

$text1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$text2 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat";
echo similarity_ratio($text1, $text2);

Output: 93.023255813953
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this PHP function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php. Consider this if speed matters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php